# React Native logical && conditional rendering ruins my layout

Tags: react-native, native-base

When I add 'report.sleep.bed.sensor.inst &&' and it's false, it messes up the width of my card

[image]

However when 'report.sleep.bed.sensor.inst' is true, it is back to normal

[image]

Except my goal is to not show the carditems when 'report.sleep.bed.sensor.inst' is false. Am I doing the conditional rendering wrong?

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Card style={styles.card}>
      <ImageBackground source={Images.historyCardBg} style={styles.cardBg} imageStyle={styles.cardBg} >
        <CardItem style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
          <Text h1>{fromNow === 1 ? I18n.t('$date_yesterday') : fromNow + ' ' + I18n.t('$reports_history_daysago')}</Text>
          <Text h2 purple>{date}</Text>
        </CardItem>
        {
          report.sleep.bed.sensor.inst &&
           <CardItem>
             <Col><Text>{I18n.t('$reports_history_sleepinbed')}</Text></Col>
             <Col style={styles.historyDataRight}><Text>{ moment.duration(report.sleep.bed.duration, 'milliseconds').hours() + ' hrs ' + moment.duration(report.sleep.bed.duration, 'milliseconds').minutes() + ' mins' }</Text></Col>
          </CardItem>
        }
        <CardItem>
          <Col><Text>{I18n.t('$reports_history_awayfromhome')}</Text></Col>
          <Col style={styles.historyDataRight}><Text>{report.outside.sensor.inst ? moment.duration(report.outside.duration, 'milliseconds').hours() + ' hrs ' + moment.duration(report.outside.duration, 'milliseconds').minutes() + ' mins' : 'N/A'}</Text></Col>
        </CardItem>
      </ImageBackground>
    </Card>
  </View>
)
```

And this is the css:

```
  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent'
  },

  cardBg: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    borderRadius: Metrics.cardBorderRadius,
    padding: Metrics.cardPadding
  },
```

Comment: What are your styles? I suspect you would need `flex: 1` on either `styles.card` or `styles.cardBg`

Comment: Yes cardBg has a flex: 1. Please see code above @aqwert